# Google App Engine PHP and Cloud SQL

Tags: php, sql, google-app-engine, pdo, google-cloud-sql

I'm attempting to connect to my Google Cloud SQL from my local development Google App PHP server. But PHP doesn't see function `mysql_connect`, it doesn't see class `mysqli` and it raises exception `could not find driver` when I'm attempting to connect with PDO class.

---

I run my development PHP server with a command:

`"C:\Users\pasha\appengine-php-sdk-1.8.0\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py" --php_executable_path="C:\Users\pasha\php\php-cgi.exe" C:\Work\gaetest\`

---

The `app.yaml` file has these contents:

```
application: gaetest
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /(.*)
  script: app/\1
```

---

The testing sript is:

```
define('MYSQL_HOST', "/cloudsql/sample-project:sample-sql-instance");
define('MYSQL_LOGIN', "sample-login");
define('MYSQL_PASSWORD', "sample-pass");
define('MYSQL_DB', "sample-db");

echo "\nfunction_exists('mysql_connect'):\n"; 
var_dump(function_exists('mysql_connect'));

echo "\nclass_exists('mysqli'):\n"; 
var_dump(class_exists('mysqli'));   

try{

    echo "\nUse PDO\n";
    $db = new PDO(
        'mysql:unix_socket='.MYSQL_HOST.';dbname='.MYSQL_DB.';charset=utf8',
        MYSQL_LOGIN,
        MYSQL_PASSWORD
    );
}catch(Exception $e){
    var_dump($e->__toString());
}
```

---

Output of the testing script:

```
function_exists('mysql_connect'):
bool(false)

class_exists('mysqli'):
bool(false)

Use PDO
string(371) "exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\Work\gaetest\app\test.php:19
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Work\gaetest\app\test.php(19): PDO->__construct('mysql:unix_sock...', 'sample-login', 'sample-pass')
#1 C:\Users\pasha\appengine-php-sdk-1.8.0\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\php\setup.php(45): require('C:\Work\gaetest...')
#2 {main}"
```

---

How can I use Google Cloud SQL from my PHP development server?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot connect to the real CloudSQL instance from your development server. You need to test against a local install of MySQL when developing your app.

Comment: How do we do this? I already have WampSerevr which includes MySQL. How can I get the SDK use this MySQL?

Comment: that is not true. You can connect to the real CloudSQL using the google cloud sql proxy. tested by me.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_PHP

HOWEVER, you should use this configure command:

```
./configure --prefix=$PWD/installdir --enable-bcmath --with-mysql --with-pdo-mysql
```

You might be able to run that configure command after-the-fact, but I'm unsure TBH

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to install the mysql and mysqli extensions in your local environment.

Comment: How can I do it? There is said that functions `mysql_connect` and others are available by default in Google app engine PHP SDK. For example here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/developers-guide?hl=en.

Comment: These functions are provided by the PHP that you install (or may be already installed with your OS). The documentation provides instructions on how you can install a version of PHP with these extensions enabled. Here's the instructions for Windows - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/installingwindows

Comment: Thank you. I have sold my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have sold my problem.

1. I have renamed `php.ini-development` file in `php` folder to `php.ini`
2. Then I have enabled the needed extensions in my `php.ini`
3. I have decommented the line `extension_dir = "ext"` in my `php.ini`, so php will now see the extensions.

That's all. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy php.ini into the project local path (the same directory as the app.yaml file) with the pdo extension uncommented.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/php_ini

It works for me.